Error starting at line : 311 in command - DECLARE in oracle sql
I was coding coding in Oracle, when I encounter an issue Declare and syntax, but I don't know where is it

Error starting at line : 311 in command -

DECLARE
    v_commune_id NUMBER;
    v_district_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR stress IN (SELECT * FROM tbl_dm_stress) LOOP
        BEGIN
            -- Xác ??nh ID c?a District
            BEGIN
                SELECT ID INTO v_district_id
                FROM tbl_dm_district
                WHERE NAME = stress.DISTRICTS;
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                    INSERT INTO tbl_dm_district (NAME, ACTIVE)
                    VALUES (stress.DISTRICTS, 1)
                    RETURNING ID INTO v_district_id;
            END;
        END;

        BEGIN
            -- Xác ??nh ID c?a Commune v?i ?i?u ki?n theo tên District
            BEGIN
                SELECT ID INTO v_commune_id
                FROM tbl_dm_commune
                WHERE NAME = stress.COMMUNES
                AND ID_DISTRICT = v_district_id;
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                    INSERT INTO tbl_dm_commune (NAME, ACTIVE, ID_DISTRICT, ID_PROVINCE, CODE_COMMUNE_WEB)
                    VALUES (stress.COMMUNES, 1, v_district_id, NULL, NULL)
                    RETURNING ID INTO v_commune_id;
            END;
        END;

        -- Insert vào b?ng tbl_dm_stress_detail
        INSERT INTO tbl_dm_stress_detail (
            STRESS_ID, STRESS_NAME, COMMUNE_ID, COMMUNE_NAME, DISTRICT_ID, DISTRICT_NAME,
            ACTIVE, CREATE_DATE, CREATE_BY, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, LAST_UPDATE_BY
        )
        VALUES (
            stress.ID, stress.STRESS_NAME, v_commune_id, stress.COMMUNES, v_district_id, stress.DISTRICTS,
            1, SYSDATE, stress.CREATE_BY, SYSDATE, stress.LAST_UPDATE_BY
        );
    END LOOP;
END;

I try run to code, but I get this exception

Error starting at line : 311 in command -
DECLARE
v_commune_id NUMBER;
v_district_id NUMBER;

and

Error report
ORA-06550: line 37, column 76:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DISTRICT_NAME": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 36, column 9:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.


Errors are often reported right after they occur. You can't post a few lines that are out of context when there are 300+ lines before that and expect us to know what is wrong. You're going to need to start reducing your code to isolate the issue to an actual location. Once you've done that, you can come back here and ask for help and include that portion of your code.

ORA-00904 means that you're trying to use a column that doesn't exist.
Offending line is #37, which is
INSERT INTO tbl_dm_stress_detail

while column that Oracle complains about is named DISTRICT_NAME.
Therefore, double check whether table tbl_dm_stress_detail contains it.
If it looks as if it does, but your code still doesn't work, then post table description - result of DESCRIBE command, or select from user_tab_columns for that table, or a screenshot from GUI you might be using, ... Just don't say "it exists". I'd like to see it.
A few hints:

did you misspell its name while creating the table?
did you enclose column name into double quotes, but didn't use CAPITAL letters for that column name?


Thank you, I found a issue, which is column didn't exist
